# NameError: name '__callback' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

Estoy intentando usar `gupnp` (librería GNU para operaciones UPnP y DLNA), usando GObjectIntrospection:

```
import functools
import gi
gi.require_version( 'GSSDP', '1.0' )
from gi.repository import GSSDP
from gi.repository import Gtk

__callback = None
__network = None
__msgType = None
__client = None
__browser = None

def start( cb, network = '0.0.0.0', msgtype = 'ssdp:all' ):
  global __client, __browser, __callback
  # Si ya hay un descubrimiento en marcha, no hacemos nada.
  if __client != None:
    if cb == __callback:
      return
    else:
      raise( 'Ya hay un descubrimiento en marcha' )

  __callback = cb
  __client = GSSDP.Client.new( )
  __client.set_network( network )

  __browser = GSSDP.ResourceBrowser.new( __client, msgtype )
  __browser.connect( 'resource-available', __available )
  __browser.connect( 'resource-unavailable', __unavailable )
  __browser.set_active( True )

def stop( ):
  __browser.set_active( False )

def __available( notUsed, msn, locations ):
  __callback( msn, locations )

def __unavailable( notUsed, msn ):
  __callback( msn, None )

def debug( msn, locations ):
  if locations == None:
    print( 'PERDIDO', msn )
  else:
    print( 'ENCONTRADO', msn )
    for v in locations:
      print( v )

start( debug )
Gtk.main( )
```

Funcionar, funciona, al menos en descubrir dispositivos UPnP:

> ENCONTRADO uuid:20809696-105a-3721-e8b8-c4a366da3c13::upnp:rootdevice
>   http://192.168.1.1:52869/gatedesc.xml
>   ENCONTRADO uuid:20809696-105a-3721-e8b8-c4a366da3c13
>   http://192.168.1.1:52869/gatedesc.xml
>   ...

Lo curioso ocurre cuando intento pararlo, pulsando <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "gssdp.py", line 38, in __unavailable
>   NameError: name '__callback' is not defined

¿ Como ? O_o ¡ Pero si estoy usando `__callback` en todas partes !

El mensaje completo es:

> ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
>     File "gssdp.py", line 49, in <module>Gtk.main( )
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1629, in main
>       return _Gtk_main(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 88, in **exit**
>   next(self.gen)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_ossighelper.py", line 251, in register_sigint_fallback
>       signal.default_int_handler(signal.SIGINT, None)
>   KeyboardInterrupt
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "gssdp.py", line 38, in __unavailable
>   NameError: name '__callback' is not defined
>   Error in sys.excepthook:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
>   ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

El codigo no está pensado para usarlo independiente, sino que forma parte de una aplicación Gtk. Cuando lo uso desde la aplicación real, con una ventana en pantalla, la misma curiosa excepción se produce al cerrarla, haciendo <kbd>click</kbd> en el correspondiente icono de su barra de título.

<sub>**Nota**: Estoy seguro de que **no es un error tipográfico**; he copiado/pegado `__callback`, y se sigue produciendo.</sub>

#### EDITO

He hecho unos pequeños cambios:

```
start( debug )
GObject.timeout_add( 2000, stop )
GObject.timeout_add( 2500, Gtk.main_quit )
Gtk.main( )
```

De esta forma, **detengo** el descubrimiento a los 2 segundos, y **termino** la aplicación a los 2.5 segundos.

Haciendolo así, la excepción **no se produce**.

Comment: Sólo por descartar, aunque creo que no va a haber diferencia, prueba a llamar `callback` (sin el `__`) a esa global.

Comment: He buscado/reemplazado `__callback` por `callback` (con la opción del editor, no *a mano*). Mismo resultado, pero, logicamente, ahora aparece `callback` en el mensaje de error.

Comment: Es lo que me temía. Tenía la esperanza de que quizás el `__` causaba un _name mangling_ que luego le impedía encontrarlo (en los atributos y métodos de clase lo hace, pero en los módulos creo que no). En ese caso sólo puede ser que para cuando Gtk vaya a llamar a `__unavailable()`, por alguna razón misteriosa y desconocida el _scope_ de esa función esté mal y no contenga ya `__callback` entre sus globales. Parece algo muy específico de `gi`, no he conseguido reproducir el problema sin él.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte las molestias. Yo tengo esa misma sospecha; he editado la pregunta: si detengo el descubrimiento, la excepción no se lanza. Tiene toda la pinta de ser alguna interacción *curiosa* entre `python` y gi (y/o gupnp). En fin, tendré que aprender a *vivir con ello* :-)